# SQL Server 2000: how to replace a entry with only the last 2 characters

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have a table in a SQL Server 2000 database with a column with several entries like `01-03`, `04-05`. The first 2 digits are the room number and the last two digits are the bed number.

I want to replace the `01-05`, `03-07` etc. with only the bed number. So only the last two charcters have to be in the column.

How do I accomplish this?

Sample data is:

In the column `[Bed]` with values:

```
22-01
08-01
09-03
01-16
```

Result has to be:

```
01
01
03
16
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Sample data is:
In the Column [Bed] with values:
22-01
08-01
09-03
01-16
Result has to be:
01
01
03
16

Comment: Please do not post the sample data in the comment. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

`RIGHT` should solve your problem:

```
SELECT RIGHT(RTRIM(Bed), 2) FROM tbl
```

Comment: yes we already tried this, but it is very annoying that there are in some cases a few spaces behind the value. In these cases the field is empty, and it can't be empty, there has to be a value in it

Comment: Try trimming `Bed` first. See my updated answer.

Comment: The last solution did the job. Thank you very much :)